# Puppet passing parameters from profile to module

Tags: puppet

I have a module "base" with an `init.pp` class which has some parameters as such:

```
class base (
   $listen_ip = "xx.xx.xx.xx",
   $listen_port = 3306,

   $admin_username = 'admin',
   $admin_password = 'admin',
)
{
...
}
```

Then I have created a profile "base" where I want to set some of the parameters:

```
class profile::base {
    class { 'base':
      $listen_ip = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx",
      $listen_port => 6033,
  }
}
```

Then the is a secondary profile where I want to set the username and password:

```
class profile::department::sales::base {
    class { '::profile::base':
      $admin_username = "some_user",
      $admin_password => "some_pw",
  }
}
```

However it's not possible to set the parameters from the "sales" profile.
The idea is that some values will be always the same for the base class and that some differ based on the department.

Comment: Could you please specify exactly what your question is?

Comment: I have a "generic" module `base`, some of the parameters that will be applicable for the entire enviroment I want to set from `profile::base`, other that are specific for each department I want to set from `profile::department::sales::base`

Answer (score 0):

> However it's not possible to set the parameters from the "sales" profile.

Not exactly.  What is not allowed is using two different resource-like declarations for the same class while building one manifest.  If you use even one then you must make certain that it is the first (or only) declaration of that class that the catalog builder evaluates.

To understand this, you need to appreciate that assigning parameter values is not the principal purpose of declarations such you are using.  The principal purpose is rather to specify that the class in question should be included in the catalog in the first place.  In service to that goal, values are bound to *all* the parameters of a class at the point where its first declaration is evaluated.  Thus, your two class declarations do not supplement each other.  Instead, they conflict with each other.

Even if the parameter values it specified for class `base` were identical to those declared by class `profile::base`, however, Puppet would still object to all uses of class `profile::department::sales::base`.  To simplify evaluation and be absolutely certain to avoid inconsistency, it implements a stronger constraint than is actually required: that only the first-evaluated declaration of any given class may be a resource-like one.

*Note: [the latest docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html#reference-4789__section_x54_1hk_xhb) actually specify an even stronger constraint than that: "Resource-like class declarations require that you declare a given class only once."  In practice, however, this is a simplification (in every version of Puppet so far released since the introduction of parameterized classes).  It is likely inspired by the fact that the order in which Puppet manifests are evaluated can be difficult to predict, so if you use include-like declarations along with a resource-like declaration of the same class, in different manifests, then it can be hard to ensure that the resource-like one is always evaluated first.*

> The idea is that some values will be always the same for the base
>   class and that some differ based on the department.

For most purposes it is best to avoid resource-like class declarations altogether, [relying instead on external data (Hiera) for binding values to class parameters](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html#setting-class-parameter-defaults-with-hiera-data).  Hiera recognizes a hierarchy of data sources (hence the name) and supports specifying different parameters at different levels, and even overriding data from one level at a higher-priority level.

My suggestion, then, is to leverage Hiera to assign appropriate parameter values to class `base`.  There are many ways the specifics could play out.